# Missing PDO but can still connect to table?

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble installing the drivers for PDO in php. I am currently using PHP 5.6 and SQL Server 2008. I went to the phpinfo, and it looks like the drivers are not installed.

First, though, I would like to ask if this is even necessary for me. I am currently using Webmatrix. In Webmatrix, I can go to the database panel and add a new database. All the tables from the database that I want to use show up in the database panel, and I can use it as I would SQL Server. The following code shows up in my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add connectionString="Server=hcdacltrk01pw;Database=Ravi;Trusted_Connection=True" name="Ravi" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I was wondering how I was connecting to my SQL Server database without PDO, and how I could use select, create table, etc commands if I don't have PDO?

Comment: With some quick googling I found this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php not sure if you have looked at that as of yet?

Comment: Seems like the key to this question is WebMatrix, what it does with `web.config`, and whether that has anything to do with PHP. Being able to see the tables in a control panel that is not written in PHP won't help you write PHP code to connect to them.

Comment: @Mr.concolato whilst this may provide functionality, personally I've had problems with this extension & setup, as most out of the box packages I've seen do not contain the needed extension file. Also lacking functionality which would prove beneficial such as parameterized queries